# R: Return value of next occurence by group AND from a subset of data (conditional lead/lag)

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

My question is a continuation/modification of this question: [Return value of next occurrence based on multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33147714/return-value-of-next-occurrence-based-on-multiple-columns)

I'm using the following data:

```
df<-structure(list(firm = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", 
"C", "C"), datetime = structure(c(1514793600, 1514799000, 1514793600, 
1514797200, 1514800800, 1514804100, 1514804400, 1514800800, 1514802600, 
1514802900), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    employee = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

I want to return the next `datetime` a certain `firm` occurs in the data AND the `employee` equals 0 for all the `employee`s that equal 1.

```
df_expected<-structure(list(firm = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", 
"C", "C"), datetime = structure(c(1514793600, 1514799000, 1514793600, 
1514797200, 1514800800, 1514804100, 1514804400, 1514800800, 1514802600, 
1514802900), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    employee = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L), NextTime = structure(c(1514799000, 
    NA, 1514797200, NA, 1514804400, 1514804400, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA), class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC")), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
```

I tried it with `dplyr` which works only if there is not more than one `employee=="0"` per `firm`:

```
df %>%
  group_by(firm) %>%
  mutate(nextTime=datetime[employee==0])
```

..or if there is not more than one `employee=="1"` per `firm`:

```
df %>%
  group_by(firm) %>%
  mutate(nextTime=lead(datetime))
```

I tried multiple "combinations" of the code snippets above and from the `data.table` answer to the original question, all unfruitful. I'd really appreciate your help!

Comment: Your expected output suggests that you believe `"8:00"` sorts *before* `"10:00"` and `"11:00"`, see `sort(c("8:00","11:00"))` to show this is not the case. If your `Time` variable is some numeric-like variable, please share your data using `dput` instead of strings as you've done here; if it really is strings, then if you want to preserve "human-intuitive" sort order of these times, you need to convert to a number-like object.

Comment: Ah, I didn't think of that. I thought I'd save time copying the data from the previous question. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: ..I should've added that I embraced your suggestion and edited the question.. =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```r
df_expected %>%
  group_by(firm) %>%
  mutate(NextTime2 = if_else(lead(employee == 0), lead(datetime), datetime[NA])) %>%
  tidyr::fill(NextTime2, .direction = "up") %>%
  mutate(NextTime2 = if_else(employee == 0, NextTime2[NA], NextTime2)) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 10 x 5
#    firm  datetime            employee NextTime            NextTime2          
#    <chr> <dttm>                 <int> <dttm>              <dttm>             
#  1 A     2018-01-01 08:00:00        1 2018-01-01 09:30:00 2018-01-01 09:30:00
#  2 A     2018-01-01 09:30:00        0 NA                  NA                 
#  3 B     2018-01-01 08:00:00        1 2018-01-01 09:00:00 2018-01-01 09:00:00
#  4 B     2018-01-01 09:00:00        0 NA                  NA                 
#  5 B     2018-01-01 10:00:00        1 2018-01-01 11:00:00 2018-01-01 11:00:00
#  6 B     2018-01-01 10:55:00        1 2018-01-01 11:00:00 2018-01-01 11:00:00
#  7 B     2018-01-01 11:00:00        0 NA                  NA                 
#  8 C     2018-01-01 10:00:00        1 NA                  NA                 
#  9 C     2018-01-01 10:30:00        1 NA                  NA                 
# 10 C     2018-01-01 10:35:00        1 NA                  NA                 datetime
```

FYI: the `[NA]` indexing is one trick for ensuring that the `class` of both the `true=` and `false=` vectors is the same. Had I used just `NA`, it would have failed because `NA` is class `logical`:

```r
if_else(TRUE, 1, NA)
# Error in `if_else()`:
# ! `false` must be a double vector, not a logical vector.
```

By indexing with `[NA]`, we guarantee that it will be the appropriate class (there are over 6 different types of `NA`):

```r
(1:3)[NA]
# [1] NA NA NA
class( (1:3)[NA] )
# [1] "integer"

#### many types of `NA`
class(NA)
# [1] "logical"
class( (seq(1,3,by=0.5))[NA] )
# [1] "numeric"
class( letters[NA] )
# [1] "character"
class( Sys.time()[NA] )
# [1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt" 
class( Sys.Date()[NA] )
# [1] "Date"
```